# How to debug PHPUnit tests in a library with Xdebug and eclipse / Zend Studio?

Tags: php, phpunit, libraries, xdebug, zend-studio

For development and debugging I use the combination Zend Studio 12 + Xdebug. The projects are stored on a Windows 7 local machine, shared with as `shared folders` with a Linux Virtualbox VM, and executed there. It's my environmnet looks like.

The debugging works and I can also debug (vendor) libraries within a "common" project. But if the IDE project is a library or a container with multiple libraires, it doesn't have 1. a URL (like `my-project.loc`) and 2. an index file. I've faked the URL and the `index.php`:

[image]

but it's not working.

**How to get Xdebug working with Zend Studio for PHPUnit code in the context of a library / container IDE project?**

Answer (score 1):

The mappings for PHPUnit of every library needed to be set up, then it worked.

`Window -> Preferences -> PHP -> Servers -> [entry] my-server-name -> [button] Edit -> [tab] Path Maping`:

[image]

```
/var/www/my-project                                     /my-project
/usr/local/lib/phpunit-4.8.phar/phar/phpunit/Framework  /my-project/path/to/library-foo/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/tests
/usr/local/lib/phpunit-4.8.phar/phar/phpunit            /my-project/path/to/library-bar/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src
```

All these mapping entries has been created by the IDE, after I called

```
require_once './path/to/foo/test/Bootstrap.php';
```

in the `/index.php`.

Don't know, why the library `foo` has got the mapping for the code coverage (and the other one not) and why the library `bar` has got the mapping for PHPUnit source (and the other one not). (**It would be nice, if someone could explain that.**) But anyway -- it works.